# Unhandled promise rejection Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, promise

There are similar questions about this knockout error, but for me,I am more confused about the **Unhandled Promise rejection** part. I can be sure that every single ko.apply I used have specific scope.

The error seemed to do nothing to the functionality

The JS code

```
    function SliderModel(){
        var self = this;
        self.max = ko.observable(200);
        self.min = ko.observable(0);
        self.value = ko.observable(100);
        self.step = ko.observable(10);
    }

    var sliderModel = new SliderModel();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        ko.cleanNode( document.getElementById('slider_container'));
        ko.applyBindings(SliderModel(), document.getElementById('slider_container'));
    });
```

Comment: "Unhandled Promise Rejection" just means that you had a promise chain without a `.catch` at the end of it and the tooling had your back and let you know about the error you forgot to handle anyway. Feel free to treat it like the same knockout error. In this case you have several bugs, for example you don't call `SliderModel` with `new` so it is applied to the `window` inside the `ready(` - I warmly recommend running a linter and strict mode. Happy coding!

Comment: Did you mean `ko.applyBindings(sliderModel, ...`?

Comment: @tcooc : yeah, my mistake, I meant  in my code it is also sliderModel

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : The error only popup when I include the above code. If I included a binding on the global body, will it affect all of its child?

Comment: Why do you destroy the binding and bind again?! Since you are using observable variables your view model gets updated automatically. Can't see a reason to unbind and rebind here .https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/100/